# Android: I've build custom view in layout/custom.xml How to know it's package name

Tags: android, android-layout

I have main.xml and custom.xml

I want that custom.xml will be like user control, so I've put 2 these tags into mail.xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

     <custom
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

     <custom
         xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the include tag instead.

```
<include layout="@layout/custom"
    android:id="@+id/custom1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works for me! I will accept it in 5 minutes when it will be possible

Comment: Btw, how to include this layout custom view through java code?

Comment: If you want to use this in Java then you could either do a `View customView = findViewById(R.id.custom1)` to get the view from your current layout or to add a new one you could use a `LayoutInflater` (most likely from an `Activity`) and call `View customView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom, null);` to make a new one.  Then you add that to whatever view you would like with `view.addView(customView);`.

Comment: Thank you very much, friend! You really helped me and saved a lot of time. I wish you good luck